# Export dynamic audio from Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

I'm generating a 44100hz dynamic audio stream in Flash using a flash.media.Sound object and the SAMPLE_DATA event. I'd like to be able to analyze the output instead of just listening to it.

What would be the most straightforward way of converting my Flash stream of float samples to an audio file, in a standard format that can be opened by an audio editor? Is there any audio format that would be particularly suitable for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to listen to it, there's no need to use `Sound` or the `Event.SAMPLE_DATA` at all. Just create the numbers and store them in a `ByteArray` or other data structure.

> Is there any audio format that would be particularly suitable for this?

A format that can be opened by your audio editor would be preferable.
Otherwise, this totally depends on what you want to do with the sound data.

> What would be the most straightforward way of converting my Flash stream of float samples to an audio file, in a standard format that can be opened by an audio editor?

To use an existing library that encodes the data into the specified format.

- [tonfall](https://code.google.com/p/tonfall/) supports "various audio formats Wav AIFF RAW PCM (no header) "Encoder/Decoder
- [WaveEncoder](https://github.com/oohoo/moodle-repository_capture/blob/master/flash/src/org/bytearray/waveencoder/WaveEncoder.as) from [Nicolas Bretin](https://github.com/bretin) apparently encodes to WAV
- Of course, if you know the specification, you can write your own encoder.